# Printing an std::array gives random values

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out an std::array as seen below, the output is supposed to consist of only booleans, but there seem to be numbers in the output aswell (also below). I've tried printing out the elements which give numbers on their own, but then I get their actual value, which is weird.

**My main function:**

```
float f(float x, float y)
{
    return x * x + y * y - 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<bool, ARRAY_SIZE_X>, ARRAY_SIZE_Y> temp = ConvertToBinaryImage(&f);
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)temp.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < (int)temp[0].size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << temp[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**The function that sets the array:**

```
std::array<std::array<bool, ARRAY_SIZE_X>, ARRAY_SIZE_Y> ConvertToBinaryImage(float(*func)(float, float))
{
    std::array<std::array<bool, ARRAY_SIZE_X>, ARRAY_SIZE_Y> result;

    for(float x = X_MIN; x <= X_MAX; x += STEP_SIZE)
    {
        for(float y = Y_MIN; y <= Y_MAX; y += STEP_SIZE)
        {
            int indx = ARRAY_SIZE_X - (x - X_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV;
            int indy = ARRAY_SIZE_Y - (y - Y_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV;
            result[indx][indy] = func(x, y) < 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**The constants**

```
#define X_MIN -1
#define Y_MIN -1
#define X_MAX 1
#define Y_MAX 1
#define STEP_SIZE_INV 10
#define STEP_SIZE (float)1 / STEP_SIZE_INV
#define ARRAY_SIZE_X (X_MAX - X_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV
#define ARRAY_SIZE_Y (Y_MAX - Y_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV
```

**My output:**

```
184 225 213 111 0 0 0 0 230 40 212 111 0 0 0 0 64 253 98 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 6 1 0 0 168 0 0 0
0 183 213 111 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 242 236 108
0 0 0 1 64 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 240 1 1 1 249 1 0 0
0 21 255 0 0 0 0 0 98 242 236 108 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 128 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 128 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 255 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 31 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 184 225 213 111 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 64 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 64 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 96 1 1 1 249 1 1 1
0 1 213 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 32 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
0 21 255 0 0 0 0 0 80 59 117 0 0 0 0 0 32 112 64 0
0 1 0 1 17 1 1 16 1 1 1 1 104 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 144 1 249 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 80 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 24 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 0 1 16 0 0 0 0 112 7 255 0
0 0 0 1 134 1 1 30 1 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 32 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: what are XMIN, XMAX, XSETP etc

Comment: Why are you storing floating point numbers in a bool array?

Comment: XMIN, XMAX are the range over which I evaluate the function which is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I am not storing floating point numbers, I am storing the boolean expression f(x,y) < 1

Comment: Ah, missed that `< 0` at the end.  for a bool, 0 means false and any other value is true, so this isn't really unexpected. You might be able to force strictly 0 or 1 by using double negation, ie `func(x, y) < 0` -> `!!(func(x, y) < 0)`

Comment: bools are either 0 or not 0 so those can be valid values (cout does not print true or false). Since you dont show all those constants XMIN, MAX, STEP etc its hard to say what should be happening, especially if step is > 1

Comment: Now I also tried printing std::cout << (temp[i][j] ? 1 : 0) << " "; But that results in the same error, although I specifically say to print 1 or 0

Comment: I added the constants in the post

Comment: some elements of `result` are uninitialised so your program has undefined behaviour, `indx` and `indy` also go out of bounds of the array leading to more undefined behaviour

Comment: Using floating-point values to calculate array indices often leads to off-by-one errors. Use `indx` and `indy` as the loop control variables and calculate `x` and `y` from their values. Or, at least, look at the values that they take on in the loops.

Comment: Thanks! I expressed x and y in terms of indx and indy and it worked

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't `bool` already imply strict values of `1` or `0`? It is said that `sizeof(bool)` is implementation defined, but I could't find any info if `bool` can yield something besides the 2 values. Is any compiler for c++11 and higher allowed to do that? https://godbolt.org/z/z9zcv7Ghe I would understand if a `reinterpret_cast` was somehow involved, but even type punning gives `1`

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik TIL :)  Looks like true and false are the only valid values once you have a bool: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental-10.sentence-2

Comment: Probably some UB going on with mixing floating point calculation with integer indicies.

Comment: You have a lot of out of bounds accesses: https://godbolt.org/z/a9Gqr1ebx

Comment: @NathanOliver it doesn't matter if there is any UB in comparing of floats (why would there be?). The code is printing from an `std::array` of `bool`. No casting in that place

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Not from the comparison, from the index calculation.  `ARRAY_SIZE_X - (x - X_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV;` generates a floating point result, and that result can be going out of bounds of the array, leading to UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah, but that is not the reason. Going out of bounds does not affect array's value. What does affect them (as Alan stated in his answer) is an uninitialized state. This updated example of printing out an uninitialized array reproduces the behavior https://godbolt.org/z/fzEd9dsKE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point maths will often not produce accurate results, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

If we print out the values of `indx` and `indy`:

```
20, 20
20, 19
20, 18
20, 17
20, 15
20, 14
20, 13
20, 13
20, 11
20, 10
20, 9
20, 9
20, 8
20, 6
20, 5
20, 5
20, 3
20, 3
20, 1
20, 1
19, 20
19, 19
19, 18
19, 17
...
```

You can see that you are writing to indexes with the value `20` which is out of bounds of the array and also you aren't writing to every index leaving some of the array elements uninitialised. Though normally booleans are only `true` or `false` they are usually actually stored as a byte allowing storing values between `0` and `255`, printing the uninitialised values is undefined behaviour.

We can fix your code in this particular instance by calculating the indexes a little more carefully:

```
int indx = std::clamp(int(round(ARRAY_SIZE_X - (x - X_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV)), 1, ARRAY_SIZE_X)-1;
int indy = std::clamp(int(round(ARRAY_SIZE_Y - (y - Y_MIN) * STEP_SIZE_INV)), 1, ARRAY_SIZE_Y)-1;
```

There are two fixes here, you were generating values between `1` and `20`, the `-1` reduces this to `0` to `19`. The `round` solves the issue of not using all the indexes (you were simply truncating by assigning to an `int`). The `clamp` ensures the values are always in range (though in this case the calculations work out to be in range).

As you want to always write to every pixel a better solution would be to iterate over the values of `indx` and `indy` and calculate the values of `x` and `y` from the indices:

```
for (int indx = 0; indx < ARRAY_SIZE_X; indx++)
{
  float x = X_MIN - (indx - ARRAY_SIZE_X) * STEP_SIZE;
  for (int indy = 0; indy < ARRAY_SIZE_Y; indy++)
  {
    float y = Y_MIN - (indy - ARRAY_SIZE_Y) * STEP_SIZE;
    result[indx][indy] = func(x, y) < 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can mention that unitialized state can be tackled (and should always be) by explicit initialization of the output array: `std::array<...> result{};` - gives zero-initiliazed values

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik if the intent is to write to every element then initialising the array would be wasteful

Comment: Wouldn't it be optimized?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik if you don't put it in to start with you don't need to rely on the optimiser

Comment: That contradicts modern practises where safe is better than "fast". Zero-initiliazed is guaranteed to not contain any UB. And you deploy with `-O3` in 99.999% of cases. So it boils down to whether it is guaranteed to be optimized. If you can provide cases that do not and it noticably affetcs the efficiency, I'd be glad to look at them